# SQL Filter two aggregate functions with different conditions

Tags: sql, filter, multiple-conditions

I want to get the difference between

```
AVG(arr_delay_new) 
WHERE fl_date BETWEEN '2017/07/24' AND '2017/07/31'
```

and

```
AVG(arr_delay)_new 
WHERE fl_date BETWEEN '2017/07/01' AND '2017/07/23'
```

This one of course returns 0 and has no conditions with dates.

```
SELECT 
    airline_name,
    AVG(arr_delay_new) - AVG(arr_delay_new)
FROM 
    Flight_delays F
JOIN 
    Airlines A ON A.airline_id = F.airline_id
GROUP BY 
    airline_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT airline_name,
       (AVG(CASE WHEN fl_date BETWEEN '2017-07-24' and '2017-07-31' THEN arr_delay_new END) -
        AVG(CASE WHEN fl_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-23' THEN arr_delay_new END)
       ) as AVG_DIFF
FROM Flight_delays F JOIN
     Airlines A
     ON A.airline_id = F.airline_id
GROUP BY airline_name;
```

This assumes that `arr_delay_new` has a type that can be averaged.  Some databases are reluctant to do averages on date/times directly.

Comment: If you use PostgreSql, there is cleaner way to do like:
   AVG(arr_delay_new) filter (where fl_date between '2017-07-24' and '2017-07-31')